# Is there any way to automate ssh login, without sshpass or expect?

Tags: ssh, password

The context here is that I have a series of embedded Linux systems at work. They do not have internet access. They are frequently re-imaged. I do not control the OS image and the owning team is not interested in incorporating `sshpass` or `expect` into the OS builds.

These are test machines only accessible from an internal network. Currently the update process is quite painful and involves me manually `scp`'ing files between 3 hops. I would like to automate this process with a script, it would likely save me several hours per week. The current workflow is for me to have a gigantic series of 3-deep nested tmux sessions with various panes, in which I run very similar commands. It works, but it's not fun. However as far as I can tell, there is no way to plaintext pipe a password to regular `ssh`. The password for all these machines is just `root`, since they are test & development machines only.

Things I have seen which I believe won't work:

- Shared keys: these machines are re-imaged daily to multiple times per day. I cannot expect a persistent key.
- `sshpass` or `expect`: as stated above, the OS team has declined my request to add these.
- Installing any non-default UNIX tools, since these machines have no internet access.

Comment: You say you cannot expect a persistent key… why not? If they can re-image them, they could pack in an expected key easily enough.

Comment: I do not disagree, but my pleas are falling on deaf ears and I am just trying to unblock myself here.

Comment: your task is to SCP files to the target device via 3 server hops, right? you can use Ansible to copy the file via jump host, or configure OpenSSH to establish a jump host for you, then you just SCP from your laptop to the target device. Ref: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/using-ansible-playbook-ssh-bastion-jump-host and https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host

Answer (score 1):

First, my condolences. You've been made responsible for solving this problem without being supported to do it properly. If the systems are being regulardly re-imaged, installing keys should be easily added to that build flow. If the responsible team isn't willing to do that, that seems hard to justify.

And you're right - by design, there's no way to pass ssh a password on the command line. So there aren't many options to automate further without installing something else, just as you've said.

Given the constraints - and assuming that you shouldn't store the password anywhere - I'd say a script that uses **nested SSH** (using multiple invocations of the -J flag) to reduce your hops, and having the password ready to **paste** in your paste buffer, would minimize your effort.

One more suggestion. You mention no Internet access, but if there are any scripts or tools that you could make *internally* available, you could *pull* them from that internal source to your target systems. **Pulling a single 'bootstrap' script**, and then running that script to install any other statically compiled utilities (or even certificates or SSH keys!), might be efficient. It would have to be re-done every time the systems are rebuilt, but the script could even check to see whether or not the target system has been re-imaged or not, and only install what's missing. In other words, you could automate the process of *returning rebuilt systems to supportability*.

Either way, good luck. If Hallmark made a card for this, I would get it for you. :D